# console app (C#) doesnt regonize classes from different file

Tags: c#

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ex1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            createCity("ex", 1, "ex1");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public void createCity(string name, int showOrder, string objectName)
        {
            City myObj = new City(name, showOrder);
        }
    }
}


    using System;
    
    public class City
{
    public City()
    {
        string name;
        static int code = 1;
        int showOrder;

        City(string name, int showOrder)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.showOrder = showOrder;
            this.code++;
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea why? new to C#.
It doesn't know why the class City is, I don't understand why. I created it in the same project with the add option.
I'm just trying to create a new object of the class in the main.

Comment: What is the *exact* error message you get?

Comment: Your `City` class code won't compile at the moment. You're trying to declare a static field within the parameterless constructor, and then you appear to be trying to nest another constructor within that.

Comment: The City class is defined outside of the ex1 namespace. Try moving it to its own file and include the namespace and it should work.

Comment: Beyond that - `createCity` is called without an instance to call it on, and `this.code++` won't work when `code` is a static variable...

Comment: @Pharnax: No, it's fine to not be in the same namespace. There many issues with this code, but the namespace isn't relevant. (Fixing all the other problems but leaving Program in a namespace and City not in a namespace, it compiles fine.)

Comment: Looks like you mixed up a few things. But don't worry! Don't let mistakes stop you. We all started somewhere. Make sure you understand the basics of classes and properties. Learn about constructors, properties and access modifiers. And after all... practice makes perfect :) Can't learn how to code without trying!

Answer (score 1):

- create a constructor like this:

  `public City()
  {
  }`

or with parameters:

```
public City(string name, int showOrder)
      {
          ...
      }
```

- define the properties or fields of your class outside of the constructor

`public class City
{
private string name { get; set; }
private int code { get; set; } = 1;
private int showOrder { get; set; }
}`

- Your 'code' property / field should not be static. This is causing an error in your constructor

  `int code = 1;`
- the reason you can't do createCity() inside the main method is because it is marked as static. Removing the static keyword should work.

  private void Main(string[] args)
  {
  createCity("ex", 1, "ex1");
  Console.ReadKey();
  }

However you need a static void Main(string[] args) method in a console app, so I made createCity static as well

Full working example:

```
    namespace ex1
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            createCity("ex", 1, "ex1");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void createCity(string name, int showOrder, string objectName)
        {
            City myObj = new City(name, showOrder);
        }
    }
}

public class City
{
    public City()
    {
    }

    private string name { get; set; }
    private int code { get; set; } = 1;
    private int showOrder { get; set; }

    public City(string name, int showOrder)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.showOrder = showOrder;
        this.code++;
    }
}
```

Comment: The examples you've given of properties aren't properties - they're public *fields*.

Comment: @JonSkeet because I forgot the getters and setters?

Comment: Yes. Without those, they're fields. Now it's fine to declare fields rather than properties (although I'd strongly advise against public fields) - but it's best not to confuse a newcomer with incorrect terminology.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things to fix:

`static`: Please make sure you understand this concept
This applies to:

- `static void createCity`
- `code++;`

The `City` class has multiple constructors and the class variable was defined in the wrong place.
You have to set the constructor `public` or at least `internal`:
`public City(string name, int showOrder)`

Corrected code:

Program.cs:

```cs
using System;

namespace ex1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            createCity("ex", 1, "ex1");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void createCity(string name, int showOrder, string objectName)
        {
            City myObj = new City(name, showOrder);
        }
    }
}
```

City.cs:

```cs
namespace ex1
{
    public class City
    {
        string name;
        static int code = 1;
        int showOrder;

        public City()
        {
        }

        public City(string name, int showOrder)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.showOrder = showOrder;
            code++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it still not working, im using for the city a different file and it says in the main it doesnt know what City is

Comment: You have to care about namespaces

Comment: I splitted in into different files

Comment: You don't have to add them in separate files to make it work. But it's a good practice to keep things organized :)

Comment: @Enrico I know, but it's the current case in the question. I just want to help

Comment: @WSM_Syeli what error are you getting?

Comment: @MarkusMeyer: You really *don't* need to care about namespaces - or at least, it's fine for City to be in the global namespace and Program to be in `ex1`. Normally of course I'd suggest that classes *should* be in namespaces (and ones that follow .NET naming conventions at that) but it's worth distinguishing between conventions for maintainability and what's actually *required*.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this following code :

```
using System;

namespace ex1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            City c = createCity("ex", 1, "ex1");
            Console.WriteLine(c.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static City createCity(string name, int showOrder, string objectName)
        {
            return new City(name, showOrder);
        }
    }

    public class City
    {
        private string name;
        private int code = 1;
        private int showOrder;

        public City(string name, int showOrder)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.showOrder = showOrder;
            this.code++;
        }

        public override string ToString() => $"name: {name}; code:{code}; showOrder: {showOrder}";
    }
}
```